# How to connect Mysql docker container to Grafana

Tags: docker, grafana

I run two containers on EC2 instance:

docker run -d --name=grafana -p 3000:3000 grafana/grafana

docker run --name some-mysql -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=my-secret-pw -d mysql:tag

In the Grafana dashboard when I added the host 18.211.211.211:3306

and press test, I got the following error:
dial tcp 18.211.211.211:3306: connect: connection refused

Also ran the following commands, without success:

sudo firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=public --add-port=3306/tcp

sudo firewall-cmd --reload

How to solve this, any idea?
Thank you

Comment: Is your MySQL listening on port 3306? Check your firewall (iptables, firewalld etc) is blocking the connection?

Comment: How to check.  firewall iptables, firewalld ??   ->firewall-cmd --state  -> running

Comment: -A IN_public_allow -p tcp -m tcp --dport 3306 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCE                                PT

Comment: When I stopped and run again the container I got the following error:>>>>>   docker: Error response from daemon: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint grafana (48f13318a509d098fffb708caertffda3728a8ce9e1b1b47e1425218262):  (iptables failed: iptables --wait -t nat -A DOCKER -p tcp -d 0/0 --dport 3000 -j DNAT --to-destination 172.17.0.2:3000 ! -i docker0: iptables: No chain/target/match by that name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the solution with 2 steps.

1. Expose port 3306 from your docker to you localhost by adding -p 3306:3306 and also use the version 5.7 of MySQL image.

> docker run --name some-mysql -p 443:3306 -e
> MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=my-secret-pw -d --rm mysql:5.7

2. When connecting to MySQL from Grafana use IP address of the machine rather then localhost or 0.0.0.0 or 127.0.0.1

Answer (score 1):

You have to forward the mysql port 3306 with `-p 3306:3306`. For security reasons and since you are running Grafana on the same host as MySql, I'd suggest you use docker's [bridge network](https://docs.docker.com/network/bridge/) and a private IP instead. Unfortunately the `-p` option will alter your Iptables in a way that it bypasses your firewall config. You should have a look at [this guide](https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-fix-the-docker-and-ufw-security-flaw/#:%7E:text=Why%3F,t%20apply%20to%20Docker%20containers) or the official [docker iptable docs](https://docs.docker.com/network/iptables/).

Comment: Thank you, Felix/Wasim